# angular promises and nodejs http get response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, promise

I would use the promises of angularJS to fill data to a grid. I'd like to load data "row by row" as soon as the nodeJS's server, on which use the module "mssql" with the "stream" enabled, back to client every single line from the DB.

On the client side I use these functions:

```
function asyncGreet() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var _url = 'http://localhost:1212/test';

  $http.get(_url).
    then(function(result) {
      deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
        }, function(value) {
      deferred.notify(value); //<<-- In "value" I would like to get every single row
     });
     return deferred.promise;
  }

  $scope.btnTest = function () {
            var promise = asyncGreet();
            promise.then(function(res) {
                console.log('Success: ' + res.data + "\n");
            }, function(reason) {
                console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
            }, function(update) {
                console.log('Got notification: ' + update); //<<--
            });
        };
```

On nodeJS server those:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
//sql for test
var _query = 'select top 50 * from tb_test';
var sql = require('mssql');
var connection;
var config = {
    user: 'testUser',
    password: '12345',
    server: 'localhost\\test',
    database: 'testDB',
    stream: true
};

connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(_query); 

    request.on('recordset', function(columns) {
        // Emitted once for each recordset in a query
        //res.send(columns);
    });

    request.on('row', function(row) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(row)); //<<-- I would like intercept this event on client side 
        // and get the result in my angularJS function on deferred.notify
    });

    request.on('error', function(err) {
        // May be emitted multiple times
        console.error(err)
    });

    request.on('done', function(returnValue) {
        // Always emitted as the last one
        res.end('DONE');
    });
});

});
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this with classic HTTP requests using AngularJS Client. You might want to look at using something like Socket.IO to send the results down one by one, as they are read

Comment: @Jackpot21 Check the docs of mssql for pipe method. It might be as simple as request.pipe(res)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm done it using socket.io :)

On angularJS side:

```
// count the row for test only
$scope.count = 0;
  $scope.prova = function () {
    mySocket.emit('getTableByRow', {});
    mySocket.on('resRow', function (data) {
      if (data.event == 'ROW') {
        $scope.count += 1;
      }else {
        $scope.count += " !!DONE!! ";
      }
   });
};
```

On NodeJS side:

```
[ ... connection with DB ... ]

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('getTableByRow', function (data) {
      _getTableByRow(socket, data);
  });
});
```

_getTableByRow function:

```
var _getTableByRow = function (socket, data) {
  var _query = 'select top 50 * from tb_test';
  request.query(_query);

  request.on('row', function(row) {
    // return only the ids for test 
    socket.emit('resRow', {event: 'ROW', data: row.id.toString()});
  });

  request.on('done', function(returnValue) {
    socket.emit('resRow', {event: 'DONE'});
  });

  request.on('recordset', function(columns) {
    console.log(columns);
  });

  request.on('error', function(err) {
    socket.emit('resRow', {event: 'ERROR', data: err});
  });
}
```

In this way, as soon as one row is read from the DB, it is immediately sent to the client :)